# Install old version of Aptana plugin

Tags: aptana

I'm having problems with the new Aptana plugin (version 3.0.4) and had to uninstall it. Version 3.0.3 worked perfectly for me and I'd like to install it again but can't find it nowhere :-(
Any tips on where to get that version?

Thanks for any tips

Comment: It's possible you can revert back to an old version (http://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/tis/Reverting+to+a+Previous+Version), but what's the bug?...we'd rather just fix that and push out a quick update for you.

Comment: Hi Ingo,
Thanks for the info... The problem is not a bug in Aptana but in PDT. That was I told when I filed the bug.
I will try the link you posted.

Comment: Reverting seemed to work fine, but finally stopped with an error because of unfulfilled dependencies :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To download Studio 3.0.3, you could use the following links: [Windows](http://d1iwq2e2xrohf.cloudfront.net/tools/studio/standalone/3.0.3.201107141425/win/Aptana_Studio_3_Setup_3.0.3.exe), [Mac](http://d1iwq2e2xrohf.cloudfront.net/tools/studio/standalone/3.0.3.201107141425/mac/Aptana_Studio_3_Setup_3.0.3.dmg), [Linux 32-bit](http://d1iwq2e2xrohf.cloudfront.net/tools/studio/standalone/3.0.3.201107141425/linux/Aptana_Studio_3_Setup_Linux_x86_3.0.3.zip), [Linux 64-bit](http://d1iwq2e2xrohf.cloudfront.net/tools/studio/standalone/3.0.3.201107141425/linux/Aptana_Studio_3_Setup_Linux_x86_64_3.0.3.zip), and for [Plugins](http://d1iwq2e2xrohf.cloudfront.net/tools/studio/plugin/install/studio3/3.0.3.201107141410/).

Comment: Thanks Michael... but I would need the Plugin... Do you have a link for that?

Comment: Added the link.  You could just copy it to the Work with field in Install New Software.

Comment: Thanks very much Michael... That worked and I can enjoy Aptana again :-)